# Varying text on the detail view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a table view with items. If I click on an item, it's detail view is presented.
Now each item has two enum states that represent a meaningful state.First enum has 6 different values, second enum can have 5 different values. This give me 30 combinations.
For each combination I need a unique text.

When providing the correct text in cellForRowAtIndexPath:...what technique should I use for selecting the right text from that "grid"?
A switch structure is quite big. Is there a more neat solution?

Comment: I want to know what to write, so obviously there is no code yet. But even if there was, this is a generic problem, that maybe has a language specific solution. What purpose would it serve to put here a nested switch item resolving on two enums?

Answer (score 1):

We can use power of 2 to give some unique key. And we can arbitrarily compound these unique keys and the result will still be unique. 
[History of the Binary System](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/BinaryHistory.shtml)

> The fact that every number has a unique binary representation tells us
>   that every number can be represented in a unique way as a sum of
>   powers of 2. I wish to give an independent proof due to L. Euler
>   (1707-1783) [Dunham, p 166] of the latter result.

For the code:

```
typedef enum {
    FirstTypeOne = 1 << 0,
    FirstTypeTwo = 1 << 1,
    FirstTypeThree = 1 << 2,
    FirstTypeFour = 1 << 3,
    FirstTypeFive = 1 << 4,
    FirstTypeSix = 1 << 5
} FirstType;

typedef enum {
    SecondTypeSeven = 1 << 6,
    SecondTypeEight = 1 << 7,
    SecondTypeNine = 1 << 8,
    SecondTypeTen = 1 << 9,
    SecondTypeEleven = 1 << 10
} SecondType ;

const int FirstTypeCount = 6;
const int SecondTypeCount = 5;

// First create two array, each containing one of the corresponding enum value.
NSMutableArray *firstTypeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:FirstTypeCount];
NSMutableArray *secondTypeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:SecondTypeCount];

for (int i=0; i<FirstTypeCount; ++i) {
    [firstTypeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1<<i]];
}
for (int i=0; i<SecondTypeCount; ++i) {
    [secondTypeArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1<<(i+FirstTypeCount)]];
}

// Then compute an array which contains the unique keys.
// Here if we use 
NSMutableArray *keysArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:FirstTypeCount * SecondTypeCount];
for (NSNumber *firstTypeKey in firstTypeArray) {
    for (NSNumber *secondTypeKey in secondTypeArray) {
        int uniqueKey = [firstTypeKey intValue] + [secondTypeKey intValue];
        [keysArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:uniqueKey]];
    }
}

// Keep the keys asending.
[keysArray sortUsingComparator:^(NSNumber *a, NSNumber *b){
    return [a compare:b];
}];

// Here you need to put your keys.
NSMutableArray *uniqueTextArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:keysArray.count];
for (int i=0; i<keysArray.count; ++i) {
    [uniqueTextArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i text", i]];
}

// Dictionary with unique keys and unique text.
NSDictionary *textDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:uniqueTextArray forKeys:keysArray];

// Here you can use (FirstType + SecondType) as key.
// Bellow is two test demo.
NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:FirstTypeOne + SecondTypeSeven];
NSLog(@"text %@ for uniquekey %@", [textDic objectForKey:key], key);
key = [NSNumber numberWithInt:FirstTypeThree + SecondTypeNine];
NSLog(@"text %@ for uniquekey %@", [textDic objectForKey:key], key);
```